# EntityTypeConfiguration for base classes with One-To-Many

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am unable to configure EntityFramework migration to create DB structure by the hierarchy provided.

Consider the following:

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        public EntityBase()
        {
            UId = Guid.NewGuid();
            CreateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid UId { get; set; }
    }

public class Matrix : EntityBase
{        
    public Guid PassportUId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contracts.Entities.Passport Passport { get; set; }
    public DeviceBlockType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeviceBlockBase> Blocks { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceBlockBase: EntityBase
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Guid? MatrixUId { get; set; }
    public virtual Matrix Matrix { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayBlock: DeviceBlockBase
{
    public string LotNumber { get; set; }
    public string TransNum { get; set; }

    public Guid? LockoutByUId { get; set; }
    public virtual User LockoutBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockoutFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockoutTill { get; set; }

    public Guid? LockoutReasonUId { get; set; }
    public virtual LockoutReason LockoutReason { get; set; }
}

public class Container : ArrayBlock
{
    public DateTime FillDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLearned { get; set; }
}

public class Cartridge: ArrayBlock
{
    public DateTime LoadDate { get; set; }
    public Guid LoaderUid { get; set; }
    public User Loader { get; set; }       
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
}

public class Vault: DeviceBlockBase
{
    public DateTime FillDate { get; set; }

}
```

Edited (Configuration class):

```
public abstract class BaseBlockDeviceConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : DeviceBlockBase
    {
        protected BaseBlockDeviceConfiguration()
        {


            HasOptional(x => x.MedicationMatrix)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MedicationMatrixUId);
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseArrayBlockConfiguration<T> : BaseBlockDeviceConfiguration<T> where T : ArrayBlock
    {
        protected BaseArrayBlockConfiguration()
        {
            HasOptional(x => x.LockoutBy)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LockoutByUId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasOptional(x => x.LockoutReason)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.LockoutReasonUId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class CartridgeConfiguration : BaseArrayBlockConfiguration<Cartridge>
    {
        public CartridgeConfiguration()
        {            
            HasOptional(p => p.Loader)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.LoaderUid)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
public class ContainerConfiguration : BaseArrayBlockConfiguration<Container>
    {
        public ContainerConfiguration()
        {
        }
    }
public class VaultConfiguration : BaseBlockDeviceConfiguration<Vault>
    {
        public VaultConfiguration()
        {            

        }
    }
```

The EntityTypeConfiguration builds the DB in somewhat weird structure:

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.Cartridges", newName: "DeviceBlockBases");
AddColumn("dbo.DeviceBlockBases", "FillDate", c => c.DateTime());
AddColumn("dbo.DeviceBlockBases", "IsLearned", c => c.Boolean());
AddColumn("dbo.DeviceBlockBases", "FillDate1", c => c.DateTime());
AddColumn("dbo.DeviceBlockBases", "FillDate2", c => c.DateTime());
AddColumn("dbo.DeviceBlockBases", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
DropTable("dbo.Containers");
```

It looks like EF CodeFirst refuses to generate polymorphism and is going wild.
Any ideas?

Thanks ahead

Comment: It would be best if you will also identify the principal coulmn by `.HasPrincipalKey(a => a.YourColumn)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: First, when you inherit a class which contains public property EF Core will automatically identify it as a column part of the table you declared on your DbSet.

Comment: Second, if EF Core can't find the relevant key for your virtual property, it will create a column for itself to tag the "missing" property, but if you're going to define it then you won't have to think of anything in terms of relational mapping

Comment: All 4 tables are declared with DbSet. Mapping i can fix, the main problem is, it creates one table with partially common structure, ignoring 2 tables